# how to convert a python array to a delphi array and access this array in Keras 4 Delphi

Tags: python, keras, multidimensional-array, delphi-10.3-rio

In Keras4Delphi I succesfully stored the output of a neural network into a variable. Now I want to simply read it from a Delphi array (in Delphi 10.3 Rio), not in string format but in a Double array type, from the numpy array format of Python. I get an error (Invalid variant operation) with the code I thought that should work.

### I tried the following code (for XOR test in Keras4Delphi):

var
x_test, y_test : TNDarray;

str_v : string;

y_out : TArray;

begin

x_test := TNumPy.npArray( [ [ 0, 1 ] ] );

y_test := model.Predict(x_test);

str_v := model.Predict(x_test).ToString; // --> works fine.

y_out := y_test.AsArrayofDouble;  // --> Invalid variant operation, for : "y_out := model.Predict(x_test).AsArrayofDouble" also same error.

### end.

Should I try another function instead of "AsArrayofDouble" to get the network output in a Delphi Double array? I searched for a proper function for hours but didn't find any.

Comment: Delphi do people still use that?, No offense but you might have more luck / fun with languages such as C# Python Java or c++ to get your work done in recent surveys only 3% of the devs use it. I've coded in lots of languages but even to me (i'm senior) thats an old language. You may get this done though should you want to these days?

Comment: Hi. A friend of mine always says to me I should use Python instead of Delphi/Pascal. Yet, I prefer Delphi because I've programmed in that language for more than 20 years.

Comment: I've fixed the error by myself! I had to write several new functions in PythonEngine.pas and in Python.Utils.pas. Now it works!! I get the neural network output in Variant array format with 64 bit Double.

Comment: Possibly I could upload the complete code of the working Keras4Delphi to my GitHub. When someone's interested let me know.

Comment: @Peter sadly the inventor of the Pascal language that is the base of Delphi died at the beginning of this month.  RIP Niklaus Wirth.

Comment: @RoelsRule, well if you upload it to git, perhaps you can connect more with others. 
I once knew pascal too, I remind the language guru's of Delphi/Pascal had a great impact on C# too, perhaps you  might like that language. Though for neural nets you might find a real collaborative active world in the realm of python, most inventions happens there (besides the low level c++ cuda stuff) . It might be fun as well to change languages after 20 years, I've been a coders for a long time, and i coded in about 10 to 15 languages in my life, it can be fun to learn something new.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for encouriging me to get the job done. Yesterday I uploaded the working code to GitHub : https://github.com/Roelof1986/Keras4Delphi---debugged-Delphi-10.3-Rio-/tree/main